# Swift 4 · Data conversion

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am creating an analogue clock display in iOS that also shows the difference between solar noon and clock noon, so I need to know the time of solar noon in order to calculate that difference.

This api call: `http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=today&coords=51.1,-1.0&tz=1` yields the following result (some irrelevant fields discarded):

```
{
    "year":2018,
    "month":6,
    "day":18,
    "lon":-1.000000,
    "lat":51.100000,
    "tz":1,
    "sundata":[
        {"phen":"BC", "time":"04:02"},
        {"phen":"R", "time":"04:49"},
        {"phen":"U", "time":"13:05"},  <-- ( Upper Transit/Solar Noon )
        {"phen":"S", "time":"21:22"},
        {"phen":"EC", "time":"22:09"}]
}
```

At this point I am only interested in the local time of solar noon ("13:05" as indicated in the above example) and converting it into minutes past clock noon - which is sufficiently accurate for my display purposes.

To do this, I am extracting the data into this Swift struct:

```
struct SolarData: Decodable {
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
    let lon: Double
    let lat: Double
    let tz: Double
    let sundata:  Array<[String: String]>

    /// The number of minutes past clock noon at which solar noon occurs.
    public var solarNoonOffset: Int {
        let noon = sundata
                      .filter { $0["phen"] == "U" }
                      .flatMap { $0 }
                      .filter { $0.0 == "time" }[0]
                      .value
        let solarNoonHour = Int(noon.prefix(2))
        let solarNoonMins = Int(noon.suffix(2))
        let offset        = (solarNoonHour! - 12) * 60 + solarNoonMins!
        return offset
    }
}
```

This works but feels both clumsy and verbose (even with all the error checking removed to simplify the example), so I have two linked questions:

1. In the struct, is `let sundata:  Array<[String: String]>` an efficient match to the data or too generic?
2. To what extent can the calculation of the offset be simplified?

Comment: You have to use NSDateFormatter with "HH:mm" template, as I understand it

Comment: Declare another struct with properties `phen` and `time`. Make that struct conform to `Codable` and then declare `sundata` as an array of that struct.

Comment: Agree with @Paulw11 - if your declare `SunData` struct with `phen` (you can define it as `enum Phen: String, Decodable` and `time`, then you will be able to use something like `let noon = sundata.first(where: { $0.phen == .U })!.time` instead of you multiline declaration.

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11 better to use another Struct, alternative is to `sundata.lazy.first { $0["phen"] == "U" }?["time"]`. Also please use date formatter to extract date and let it return an optional as things can fail as server can always return bad data, it is only a string

Comment: Using DateFormatter to process "HH:MM" is, of course, the obvious thing to do (once someone mentions it)!  Thanks for that.  I had a feeling that SunData should be a struct in its own right but was thrown by the array.  But it's an array of SunData properties, just waiting to be extracted.  Also obvious after it has been pointed out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines ought to work. Basically, you want to make a class for your `phen` items. You can even use an enum for phenomenon types to improve readability.

I'm sure there are other things you can do to improve readability, like defining your own `CodingKeys` enum to give your properties better names, but that's up to you. This should get you started.

```
struct SolarData: Decodable {

    struct Phenomenon: Decodable {

        enum Kind: String, Decodable {
            case
            beginCivilTwilight = "BC",
            rise = "R",
            upperTransit = "U",
            set = "S",
            endCivilTwilight = "EC",
            lowerTransit = "L"
        }

        var phen: Kind
        var time: String
    }

    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
    let lon: Double
    let lat: Double
    let tz: Double
    let sundata:  [Phenomenon]

    /// The number of minutes past clock noon at which solar noon occurs.
    public var solarNoonOffset: Int {
        let noon = sundata
            .first { $0.phen == .upperTransit }
            .map { $0.time }
        let solarNoonHour = Int(noon!.prefix(2))
        let solarNoonMins = Int(noon!.suffix(2))
        let offset        = (solarNoonHour! - 12) * 60 + solarNoonMins!
        return offset
    }
}

let testJson = """
{
    "year":2018,
    "month":6,
    "day":18,
    "lon":-1.000000,
    "lat":51.100000,
    "tz":1,
    "sundata":[
        {"phen":"BC", "time":"04:02"},
        {"phen":"R", "time":"04:49"},
        {"phen":"U", "time":"13:05"},
        {"phen":"S", "time":"21:22"},
        {"phen":"EC", "time":"22:09"}]
}
"""

let solarData = try JSONDecoder().decode(SolarData.self, from: testJson.data(using: .utf8)!)

print("Solar Noon Offset: \(solarData.solarNoonOffset)")
```

Comment: Thanks.  The "Phenomenon" struct is exactly the sort of pointer I was looking for to simplify the data extraction.